# I'm using a useDispatch custom hook and getting this error in my test: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test that a function gets called with the correct arguments, but because I'm using useDispatch from react-redux, I'm getting the following error:     Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

I've wrapped my test component in renderWithRedux like it says in the documentation.

Test Setup:

```
const renderWithRedux = (
    ui,
    { initialState, store = createStore(reducer, initialState) } = {}
  ) => {
    return {
      ...render(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>),
      store,
    };
  };
  const templateId = faker.random.number();
  const setup = () => {
    const props = {
      history: {
        push: jest.fn(),
      },
    };
    viewTemplateUrl.mockImplementationOnce(() => jest.fn(() => () => {}));
    templatePostThunk.mockImplementationOnce(
      jest.fn(() => () => Promise.resolve(templateId))
    );
    const {
      container,
      getByText,
      getByLabelText,
      rerender,
      debug,
    } = renderWithRedux(<NewTemplateForm {...props} />);
    return {
      debug,
      templateId,
      props,
      container,
      rerender,
      getByText,
      getByLabelText,
      templateNameTextField: getByLabelText('Template Name'),
      templateNameInput: getByLabelText('Template Name Input'),
      saveTemplateButton: getByText('Save Template'),
      cancelButton: getByText('Cancel'),
    };
  };


Failing test:
  test('save template calls handleSubmit, push, and viewTemplateUrl', async () => {
    const { templateNameInput, saveTemplateButton, props } = setup();
    fireEvent.change(templateNameInput, { target: { value: 'Good Day' } });
    fireEvent.click(saveTemplateButton);
    await expect(templatePostThunk).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      name: 'Good Day',
    });
    expect(props.history.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(viewTemplateUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ templateId });
  });
```

It should be passing.

Comment: Hey there, does `createStore` include the same middleware that you're using in the application? If not, it makes sense that you're seeing this error, as default redux actions are objects with a `type` field.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to mock useDispatch and wrap the parent component in renderWithRedux instead.

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import faker from 'faker';
import { NewTemplateForm } from './NewTemplateForm';

import { templatePostThunk } from '../../../redux/actions/templatePost';
import { viewTemplateUrl } from '../../../utils/urls';

jest.mock('../../../redux/actions/templatePost');
jest.mock('../../../utils/urls');
jest.mock('react-redux');

describe('<NewTemplateForm/> controller component', () => {
  useDispatch.mockImplementation(() => cb => cb());
  const setup = () => {
    const props = {
      history: {
        push: jest.fn(),
      },
    };
    const templateId = faker.random.number();
    viewTemplateUrl.mockImplementationOnce(() => () => {});
    templatePostThunk.mockImplementationOnce(() => async () => ({
      data: { id: templateId },
    }));
    const { container, getByText, getByLabelText, rerender, debug } = render(
      <NewTemplateForm {...props} />
    );
```

Comment: useDispatch.mockImplementation(() => cb => cb()); is giving error like "Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '{ <TDispatch = Dispatch<any>>(): TDispatch; <A extends Action<any> = AnyAction>(): Dispatch<A>; }'." So to resolve that we need to mock useDispatch and then do this.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to dispatch a thunk action creator:

```js
await expect(templatePostThunk).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      name: 'Good Day',
    });
```

But you're setting up the store without the thunk middleware:

```js
store = createStore(reducer, initialState)
```

You would need to add the thunk middleware to the `createStore()` call for this to work right.